# Is it possible to access particular element/object from a list in a JSTL forEach loop?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot, jstl

[image: Screenshot of list]

**Code for table in the screenshot above**

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th class="tg-address">Title</th>

        <th class="tg-houseprice">Price</th>

        <th  class="tg-crimerating">Author</th>

        <th  class="tg-schools">Category</th>

        <th  class="tg-university">Book Cover</th>

        <th  class="tg-bars">Amount in Stock</th>

        <th  class="tg-bars"> </th>
    </tr>

    <c:forEach var="o" items="${booksList}">
        <tr>
            <td width="3.5%" height="50"><c:out value="${o.title}"/></td>

            <td width="3.5%" height="50"><c:out value="${o.price}"/></td>

            <td width="3.5%" height="50"><c:out value="${o.author}"/></td>

            <td width="3.5%" height="50"><c:out value="${o.category}"/></td>

            <td width="3.5%" height="50"><c:out value="${o.image}"/></td>

            <td width="3.5%" height="50"><c:out value="${o.quantity}"/></td>

            <td width="3.5%" height="50"><a href="shoppingCart">Add Book to Shopping Cart</a></td>

         </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

**Controller method printing the list to the JSP page**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "viewallbooks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String bookList(@Valid Book book, Model model) {
    List<Book> booksList = new ArrayList<>();
    booksList = bookRepository.findAll();

    model.addAttribute("booksList", booksList);

    return "bookListPage";
}
```

I'm printing the contents of a MySQL table by passing its values into a `List` and passing this list to a `c:forEach` loop on the JSP page `bookListPage`. If you look at the table and/or screenshot you'll notice I have an option to add the book to a shopping cart (which is a list of Book Objects in the User Object Class), which will add the relevant book to the currently logged in Users book list.

The table from the screenshot is made up of a different list of book objects (i.e. all the books in stock only 3 at the moment), my question is how do I access the relevant book object after pressing the corresponding `Add Book to Shopping Cart` link.

I call this Controller method after clicking the link which will find the currently logged in user, and add the book I'm trying to pass through to their list. However I can't seem to work out the bit in the middle.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/shoppingCart", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String shoppingCart(@Valid Book book, Model model) {

      // This gets the currently logged in user
      Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      String username = loggedInUser.getName(); // Authentication for 
      User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

      // This will add the book to the user's booklist
      user.saveBookToShoppingCart(book);

    return "shoppingcart";
}
```

Comment: why don't you just send the book id to the controller method and query it again? Do you want to avoid query?If so you need to put all the property into a form and then submit it to the controller, or you can use json to do it.

Comment: Could this be done with an AJAX Query?

Comment: yeah,it can be down with ajax,but the key point is how you form your book parameters.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Would it possible to provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are missing to encapsulate your jsp code inside a `form` tag like this for example :

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{shoppingCart}" th:object="${o}" method="post">
  <td width="3.5%" height="50">
    <a href="shoppingCart">Add Book to Shopping Cart</a>
  </td>
</form>
```

I think that since you are passing an object you must use `post` method. But this make sense only if you want to create/modify a book. Since you only want to retrieve which book was selected to be added in the shopping cart, i would sugget also follow [lucumt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3176419/lucumt) advise and pass only the id and then retrieve the book. Something like this :

```
<td width="3.5%" height="50">
  <a href="<c:url value='/shoppingcart/${o.id}' />">
    Add Book to Shopping Cart
  </a>
</td>
```

Finally your controller method sould look like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = " /shoppingcart/{bookId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String shoppingCart(@PathVariable("bookId")int bookId, Model model) {

  // This gets the currently logged in user
  Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  String username = loggedInUser.getName(); // Authentication for 
  User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

  //Retrieve book
  Book book = bookService.findBookById(bookId);

  // This will add the book to the user's booklist
  user.saveBookToShoppingCart(book);

  return "shoppingcart";
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, that worked perfectly. I was unaware of `c:url` so using this was a much better way than calling the ajax query via a regular href. Thanks!